# Cannot deploy GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I have recently started encountering the following error while deploying

```
2016-11-15 16:37:37,380 ERROR appcfg.py:1873 Invalid character in filename: lib/setuptools/script (dev).tmpl
```

What is the purpose of the file `lib/setuptools/script (dev).tmpl` and is it okay to be added to the skip list?

Here is the content of the file

```
$ cat script\ \(dev\).tmpl
# EASY-INSTALL-DEV-SCRIPT: %(spec)r,%(script_name)r
__requires__ = %(spec)r
__import__('pkg_resources').require(%(spec)r)
__file__ = %(dev_path)r
exec(compile(open(__file__).read(), __file__, 'exec'))
```

Update: It's a python app and I am deploying using the GoogleAppEngineLauncher app on Mac.

Update 2: I just removed the file, and things are working fine including local runs and remote deployments so far. I'll report back if I run into any issues.

Comment: I think the problem is with the filename special charactor `(`

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right, but what's the resolution?

Comment: how you are deplying to appenigne. is it a python or java application?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I never used that. alternatively try to use appengine commnd prompt or gcloud command prompt.

Comment: The launcher is just a UI wrapper - command prompt led to the same error message. Anyway, I removed the offending file and haven't noticed any negative consequence so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `setuptools` is this [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), I can't imagine how that would end up in your app folder.

You should probably delete the entire `setuptools` directory under `lib`.  On a mac, setup tools should be in a location like this:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools

and not in your app engine project.

Comment: Could be installed as a dependency for another third party library like for some reason is the case with the [`icalendar`](https://github.com/collective/icalendar) package...